# OpenCV waitKey in python doesn't work on mac

Tags: python, opencv

I'm writing code to face recognition in python and i'm using open cv on mac (PyCharm).
I don't understand why:

```
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
```

doesn't work on mac, but on windows this code work.
In particular q doesn't trigger the if.

I try to change with:
 k = cv2.waitKey(0)
 if k == 27:
     break

Below write my code

```
def run(self):
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    try:
        while self.active:
            # Grab a single frame of video
            ret, frame = video_capture.read()

            # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
            rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

            # Find all the faces and face enqcodings in the frame of video
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

            # Loop through each face in this frame of video
            for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
                # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(self.known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

                name = "Unknown"

                # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
                if True in matches:
                    first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                    name = self.known_face_names[first_match_index]

                # Draw a box around the face
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

                # Draw a label with a name below the face
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
                cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
                if (name != "Unknown"):
                    self.reco.emit(name)
                    self.deactivate()
                    video_capture.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                else:
                    self.unreco.emit()
                    self.deactivate()
                    video_capture.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            # Display the resulting image
            # cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
            # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    except:
        print("error while recognize")
```

Comment: could you be a little more specific? what does `doesn't work` mean? do you get an error? does `q` not trigger the if? did you try clicking the opencv window and then hitting `q`?

Comment: if i press q, q not trigger the if

Comment: OK, so did you inspect the return value from `cv2.waitKey` to see what it actually returns when you press `q`? Is there a window present? (I see the only `imshow` commented out -- perhaps it needs a window to be able to capture keyboard events?)

Comment: Returns -1 before i type from the keyboard, (for the window there's video_capture.read() i think)

Comment: Isn't PyCharm some dev environment? Maybe it grabs keyboard input. Try running outside of PyCharm, maybe.

Comment: With the terminal it's the same, i think is a conflict with pyqt5, it's possible?